# why stdout can't be substituted?

Tags: c, stdout, glibc

for educational purposes, i'm trying to substitute the standard streams stdout, stdin, and stderr. i first looked up the data type of the streams, which i traced back to the struct _IO_FILE with the following members (gdb ptype _IO_FILE):

```
type = struct _IO_FILE {
    int _flags;
    char *_IO_read_ptr;
    char *_IO_read_end;
    char *_IO_read_base;
    char *_IO_write_base;
    char *_IO_write_ptr;
    char *_IO_write_end;
    char *_IO_buf_base;
    char *_IO_buf_end;
    char *_IO_save_base;
    char *_IO_backup_base;
    char *_IO_save_end;
    struct _IO_marker *_markers;
    struct _IO_FILE *_chain;
    int _fileno;
    int _flags2;
    __off_t _old_offset;
    short unsigned int _cur_column;
    signed char _vtable_offset;
    char _shortbuf[1];
    _IO_lock_t *_lock;
    __off64_t _offset;
    void *__pad1;
    void *__pad2;
    void *__pad3;
    void *__pad4;
    size_t __pad5;
    int _mode;
    char _unused2[20];
}
```

then i tried to duplicate the memory content of the stdout pointer:

```
_IO_FILE f1 = {._flags = -72540028, ._offset = -1, ._old_offset = -1, ._fileno = 1, ._chain = stdin, ._lock = stdout->_lock, .__pad2 = stdout->__pad2 };
_IO_FILE *f2 = stdout;
_IO_FILE *f3 = malloc(sizeof(_IO_FILE));
memcpy(f3, stdout, sizeof(_IO_FILE));

fprintf(&f1, "f1\n"); // doesn't work 
fprintf(f2, "f2\n"); // works
fprintf(f3, "f3\n"); // doesn't work
```

however, only the pointer assignment doesn't crash. i compared the memory content via gdb and all share the same struct member content.

although this question is likely platform-dependent: do fprintf and the other library functions just compare the pointer to the standard streams?

edit: i suspected, that this is an implementation or platform dependent issue and since all opinions suggest, that it is, i accepted the answer which suggests one possible cause of the problem.

edit2: to narrow down the scope of the problem: i am using a 64 bit ubuntu with version 12.04 and an EGLIBC version of 2.15.

Comment: This is *totally* implementation-dependent.  To find out the answer, you should inspect the source code for your implementation (which is essentially what anyone else would have to do in order to write an answer this question...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  But somebody could help by saying what to be checked and where to search. As you did. It is the answer already. It is not the reason for closing.

Comment: Investigated on a linux device. Managed to stop the segmentation.  It would appear that the stdout structure holds a lock. Copying the structure is not sufficient.   See line 43: http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/18356174

Comment: I personally dislike that individuals put questions on hold when they have had very little time to be addressed.

Comment: @Corvusoft: "On hold" is not down to any one person, it requires 5 individual votes.  Plus, the whole point is that if the question is improved, then it can be reopened.

Comment: i tried to improve the question by naming the implementation, for which i would prefer an answer. however, the question is still on hold. what part of the question do i still have to improve?

Answer (score 1):

Per a comment from [Corvus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394663/corvusoft), on a Linus system, a lock is associated with the stream, so copying the FILE data structure interferes with lock semantics.

(I suggest this answer not be accepted immediately, to give Corvus time to enter an answer.)

---

Old hypothesis:

I suspect, in your C implementation, the location of a FILE object is used as part of its meaning. E.g., there may be an array of them, and a pointer to the first element of the array is subtracted from the pointer to a FILE object to find its index in the array. Then this index is used as the file number in system calls such as `write`.

When you allocate new space, it is not in this array, and the pointer arithmetic gives the wrong result.